# Taking a string of numbers, chopping it up into groups of 5, and storing these values as an int array

Tags: java, arrays, string, int

Okay, I have a problem with taking numbers and storing them into an int array.  I have the basic outline of the code, but I'm having trouble storing them in a way that displays when there is a 0 in front of a group of non-zero numbers.

For example, when I do this:

```
String s = "030142165109876";
private static void breakCode(String s){
    int x = s.length(), m = 0, l = x/5;
    String[] array = s.split("");
    int[] output = new int[l+1];
    int[] results = new int[array.length];

    for(int i = 0; i < x/5; i++){
        double y = 0;
        if(i == 0){
            for(int r = 5; r >= 0; r--){
                try {results[m] = Integer.parseInt(array[m]);} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
                y = y + (Math.pow(10, r) * results[m]);
                m++;
            }
            output[i] = (int) y;
            System.out.println(output[i]);
        }
        if (i != 0){
            for(int r = 4; r >= 0; r--){

                try {results[m] = Integer.parseInt(array[m]);} catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {};
                y = y + (Math.pow(10, r) * results[m]);
                m++;
            }
            output[i] = (int) y;
            System.out.println(output[i]);
        }

    }
}
```

The output for this code is:

```
3014
21651
9876
```

How do I get the zero to be held in place on the left hand side?  I know it's because I'm using power functions and the leftmost value to that power wont show up when printing.  Is there any way to force the int array to hold 5 digits so that when the number is less than 10000 it will hold the left most value as 0?  The second line doesn't start with a 0 so it holds all 5 digits properly, but not the first and third (I wrote the numbers as an example, the real program uses randomized digits).

Full disclosure, this is for an assignment, but the programmatic methods I've thought up to solve this issue don't solve it.  I have searched for my specific problem extensively throughout this website (trust me, I've grown to love searching through here), but I haven't picked up any useful tidbits regarding this specific problem.  This is also my own way of solving the problem, and if there's a way of holding 5 digits for a place in an int array then I'd love to do it with my solution rather than having my friend's coding buddy come up with a really elegant solution that isn't my own brainchild.

Thank you

P.S. I'm very verbose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First split the input into strings 5 chars long, then parse them into `int`s:

```
String[] parts = str.split("(?<=\\G.{5})");
int[] nums = new int[parts.length];
for (int i = 0; i < parts.length; i++)
    nums[i] = Integer.parseInt(parts[i]);
```

The regex for `split()` causes a split after every 5 chars - the `\G` (end of last match) ensures no overlap.

It's unclear what your exact problem is, but if it's just outputting the numbers with leading zeroes intact, I would just output `parts` and not bother with parsing them into an `int[]`. IF it's about outputting `int` values with leading zeroes, use

```
System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00000").format(nums[i]));
```

Zeros in format patterns mean always print a digit there.

Comment: Bohemian's method works!  Thank you so much.  This is what my code ended up looking like.  And to answer you, I was supposed to output int values for whatever reason.  First time professors dont make sense sometimes

    System.out.println(new DecimalFormat("00000").format(output[i]));

Answer (score 0):

Numbers are always stored[1] and printed without zeroes by default. It is how Java (and almost all other languages) work.

If you just want to *print* 5 digits, consider [`printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html).

```
printf("%05d\n", output[i]);
```

If you really want to always *store* 5 digits, use `String[]` and split using [`String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) methods. The `substring` method of `String` should do what you want easily.

[1] Conceptually (and in most, if not all, practical purposes) we treat numbers are stored without leading zeroes. In fact, strictly speaking, it does not. Java allocates some memory to store your numbers, and set this piece of memory with zeroes. As a whole memory piece, it *does* have leading zeroes, but the underlying processing throw these zeroes away, because this is how we understand numbers.

Comment: I have no idea how my teacher expects us to print out leading zeroes then.  The printf solution you provided does right align my output, which is wonderful, but still no leading zeroes.  I honestly have trouble with what our professor wants us to do one this one.  Sounds like there is no real way of putting leading zeroes when printing an integer

Comment: Updated my answer, try `%05d`